# gtesting a custom class

Tags: ros, gtest, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created the test/myTest.cpp file, which includes the myClass.h header file.

When I compile with make test I get the error ‘MyClass’ does not name a type, where MyClass is the class defined in myClass.h (the error is located where I declare a new MyClass variable)

I think I am missing something with the cmakelists file..

What should I do to compile everything correctly?

I am using ros electric..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48756/gtesting-a-custom-class/) by [Francesco Sacchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3259/francesco-sacchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your CMakeList should look something like this:

*rosbuild_add_library(myClass_lib src/myClass.cpp)*

*rosbuild_add_gtest(myTest test/myTest.cpp)*

*target_link_libraries(myTest myClass_lib)*

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2012-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Francesco Sacchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3259/francesco-sacchi/) on 2012-11-21**:
You are absolutely right... Everything was correct but I forgot to use the right namespace, which caused the error..